# FastFermenter System

Tags: temperature

Is anyone using fastferment conical with the temp jacket to eliminate secondary fermenter?  I am having trouble maintaining my temperature according to the instructions.  Does anyone have a suggestion to maintain a lower temp?

Answer (score 2):

Only moving the fermenter to a brew fridge or a cool place like a cellar would cool the fermenting vessel noticeably and with ease. I have seen desperate brewers using multiple "ice packs" (in plastic containers) placed inside the insulating jacket. Obviously this needs constant maintenance to be effective. But is does work.

If only a few degrees of cooling is required then wrapping a damp "tea towel" around the fermenter will cool it by evaporation. There will need to be some (slight) airflow to keep the evaporation going - use a slow fan it all else fails. The towel will obviously have to be re-dampened periodically.